# Radio Buttons jQuery

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to show a div with input fields of a radio button choice, `Yes` or `No`.

HTML

```
<input id='companyreg' name='companyreg' class='radio' type='radio' value='yes' /> Yes
<input id='companyreg' name='companyreg' class='radio' type='radio' value='no' /> No
```

The Jquery

```
var compfieldset = $("#companyfieldset");
//if javascript hide comp field
compfieldset.hide();
$("#companyreg").click(function(){
    var value = $("input[@name=companyreg]:checked").val();
    if (value === "yes") {
        compfieldset.slideDown();
    }
    if (value != "yes") {
        compfieldset.slideUp();
    }
});
```

Please can you help me out guys.

**EDIT**

Sorry.

When I click on No, nothing happens.

If I click on yes, the fieldset shows.

Comment: You did not tell us what your issue is. What’s your problem?

Comment: @kissaki . sorry friend. please see OP edit

Comment: “When I click on No, nothing happens.” And? What did you expect? What are you trying to achieve with your code? “show divs” doesn’t need JavaScript. Elaborate on what you’re trying to do with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two elements in the same document with the same ID. Your selector, #companyreg, is finding the first element and not the second. If you were to check the

```
$("#companyreg").length
```

you'd see 1.

You could probably get past this by using

```
$( '[id="companyreg"]' )
```

though it wouldn't fix your invalid document.  The best way would be to remove the ID and add a class to those elements, then select via that class.

I have't checked the rest of your code to see if that's the only issue, but I suspect it's the biggest one.

Answer (score 4):

**IDs have to be unique.** Use classes instead:

```
<input class='companyreg radio' name='companyreg' type='radio' value='yes' /> Yes
<input class='companyreg radio' name='companyreg' type='radio' value='no' /> No
```

and the event handler can be simplified to:

```
$(".companyreg").click(function(){
    if (this.value === "yes") {
        compfieldset.slideDown();
    }
    else {
        compfieldset.slideUp();
    }
});
```

There is not need for the `:selected` selector in your event handler. Unlike for checkboxes, the clicked radio button *is* the selected button.

Alternatively you can ditch `class` and `id` and use an attribute selector:

```
$('input[name=companyreg]')
```

You could also consider to use *event delegation* using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). There is no need to bind the same event handler to both of the elements.

---

*Why does it not work with multiple IDs?*

IDs have to be unique, the behaviour of retrieving elements by ID if they have the same ID is not specified. However, most browsers return the *first* element that appears at the DOM, that is why the event handler is only bound to the `yes` radio button.

Comment: You have two different class attributes in your example.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Oops, I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. It's hard to tell, but I think your answer is part of the answer at least. I gave you a vote.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not specific enough to know what the problem is, but I can point out some issues:

```
var compfieldset = $("#companyfieldset");
//if javascript hide comp field
compfieldset.hide();
$("#companyreg").click(function(){
    var value = $("input[@name=companyregyes]:checked").val();
    if (value == "yes") {
        compfieldset.slideDown();
    } else {
        compfieldset.slideUp();
    }
});
```

1. You don't need to check === on "yes" - it's always going to type check the yes as a string here
2. The second `if` you don't need if there are only two states, Yes and No.

Also, do you have something like...

```
<div id="companyfieldset">
 <input id='companyregyes' name='companyreg' class='radio' type='radio' value='yes' /> Yes
 <input id='companyregno' name='companyreg' class='radio' type='radio' value='no' /> No
</div>
```

As well as all ID attributes need to be unique, as in (see above id attribute).

Comment: As you noticed yourself, this is not an answer to the question. Comments should be added as comments to the question.

Comment: Thanks Kissaki. See my edit referring to ID's. It's difficult to point out other issues without posting code in an answer, per se. I'll take my lumps.

Comment: FWIW, using === is always best. Sure, JS is loose and all, but it's best to know what you're looking for and stick to it. It wouldn't effect this code at all, though.

Comment: @JAAulde - And thus, my point is correct; it's not needed here. And it's NOT always best.